# Call javascript method variable loses 'this'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've created a simple pointer to a method like so:

```
export class SmbwaService {
    getExistingArsByLab(labId: number): Observable<SmwbaAr[]> {
        this.otherMethod();
    }

    otherMethod(): void {
    }
}


let method: (x: number) => Observable<SmbwaAr[]>;
method = this.service.getExistingArsByLab;
method(12);
```

That executes OK insofar as it does call `getExistingArsByLab` method.  However, I then get an error when it tries to call `otherMethod` because:

> Cannot read property otherMethod of undefined.

What's the right way to do this?  Obviously in my actual code `method` is being set to one of a number of different methods based on some conditions.

Comment: I'm assuming the last 3 lines of code in your example are actually inside of another class where you set `service = new SmbwaService()`, right?

Comment: @ChrisBarr Yes.  jspcal's answer was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Keep in mind that `this` in JavaScript vs.`this` in a Typescript class are two entirely different things.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to obtain a function reference that's bound to a particular value of `this`:

```
method = this.service.getExistingArsByLab.bind(this.service)
method(2)
```